# When would I use model.to("cuda:1") as opposed to model.to("cuda:0")?

Tags: pytorch

I have a user with two GPU's; the first one is AMD which can't run CUDA, and the second one is a cuda-capable NVIDIA GPU. I am using the code `model.half().to("cuda:0")`. I'm not sure if the invocation successfully used the GPU, nor am I able to test it because I don't have any spare computer with more than 1 GPU lying around.

In this case, does "cuda:0" mean the first device which can run CUDA, so it would've worked even if their first device was AMD? Or would I need to say "cuda:1" instead? How would I detect which number is the first CUDA-capable device?

Comment: You can always use `nvidia-smi` to check if anything is running on the Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how this could be used to help me or answer my question though? I don't have any test computer with multiple GPU's. What nvidia-smi or any other utility says for my computer is irrelevant to that user's situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it and as I suspected the `model.half().to("cuda:0")` will put your model in the first available GPU with CUDA support i.e. NVIDIA GPU in your case, the AMD GPU isn't visible as a cuda device, feel safe to assume cuda:0 is only a CUDA enabled GPU, and AMD GPU won't be seen by your program.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

The package `nvidia-smi` can help to track GPU's memory while running your code.
To install, run `pip install nvidia-ml-py3`. Take a look at this code snip:

```py
import nvidia_smi

cuda_idx = 0 # edit device index that you want to track
to_cuda = f'cuda:{cuda_idx}' # 'cuda:0' in this case

nvidia_smi.nvmlInit()
handle = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(cuda_idx)

def B2G(num):
    return round(num/(1024**3),2)

def print_memory(name, handle, pre_used):
    info = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
    used = info.used
    print(f'{name}: {B2G(used)}')
    print(f'This step use: {B2G(used-pre_used)}')
    print('------------')
    return used

# start
mem = print_memory('Start', handle, 0)

model = ... # init your model
model.to(to_cuda)

mem = print_memory('Init model', handle, mem)
```

Above is the example with `nvidia-smi` that can help to track the memory that needs for each part of the model and print it in GB unit.

#### Edited: To check the list of GPUs:

```py
def check_gpu():
    for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
        device_name = f'cuda:{i}'
        print(f'{i} device name:{torch.cuda.get_device_name(torch.device(device_name))}')
```

Comment: If the user's 1st GPU is an AMD GPU, and 2nd GPU is an NVIDIA GPU, and I call this code with cuda_idx set to 0, will it return the AMD card's information (even if it can't run CUDA) or the NVIDIA card's information?

Comment: First, I just edited the answer at line: `model.to(to_cuda)`, the nvidia_smi should check the same GPU with the model, `model.cuda()` will move the model to default GPU. Second, the index of GPU is arranged from 0, so in your case, the `cuda_idx` should be 1 (GPU1, AMD: 0; GPU2, NVIDIA GPU: 1)

Comment: I just need to find the first GPU that can run CUDA. If the AMD GPU gets returned as an eligible device even though it can't run CUDA, then I need a way to check if the GPU of a given index can run CUDA. Do you know the right function to call? It doesn't matter how much VRAM the AMD GPU has if it can't run CUDA in the first place.

Comment: I just edited the answer, with that function, you can check the index of cuda device then use it as `cuda_idx` into the above function to check the amount of memory that it needs for your model. I haven't had experience with AMD GPU, so I don't know if cuda index is include AMD or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of methods of [`torch.cuda`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html) to query and monitor GPU devices.
For example, you can check the type of each device:

```py
torch.cuda.get_device_name(torch.device('cuda:0'))
% or
torch.cuda.get_device_name(torch.device('cuda:1'))
```

In my case, the output of `get_device_name` returns:

> ```
> 'Quadro RTX 6000'
> ```

If you want a more programmatic way to explore the properties of your devices, you can use [`torch.cuda.get_device_properties`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.get_device_properties.html#torch.cuda.get_device_properties).

Once you are working with a device (or believe you are), you can use [`torch.cuda`]'s [memory management functions](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#memory-management) to monitor GPU memory usage.
For instance, you can get a very detailed account of the current state of your device's memory using:

```py
torch.cuda.memory_stats(torch.device('cuda:0'))
% or
torch.cuda.memory_stats(torch.device('cuda:0'))
```

If you want `nvidia-smi`-like stats on utilization, you can use [`torch.cuda.utilization`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.utilization.html#torch.cuda.utilization)

Comment: I am wondering if "cuda:0" gets the first GPU, or the first cuda-eligible GPU? For example what happens if the first gpu is AMD? Will it return the AMD card's memory and info, or will it just not be detected?

Comment: @pete I guess you'll have to run these commands on your machine with the two GPUs and see for yourself. But essentially, `torch.cuda` gives you all the methods you need to inspect _programatically_ your GPUs and decide which is the device you want to work on.

Comment: I don't have two GPUs or an AMD GPU to test with. That's why I'm asking this question. I agree that some of those methods can be used programatically but my program will still need to know whether the non-CUDA GPU is returned as part of the list of devices. If non-CUDA GPU is included, then I need a way to programmatically check if it can run CUDA. If it's not included, my program can assume that GPU 0 is legit.